# findPattern() Python Code...not executing correctly?

Tags: python, design-patterns

my homework assignment was to: "write a function called findPattern() which accepts two strings as  parameters, a filename and a pattern. The function reads in the file specified by the given filename and searches the file’s contents for the given pattern. It then returns the line number and index of the line where the first instance of this pattern is found. If no match is found, your function should return -1 for both the line number and index."

I was fairly certain that my code was accurate until it would execute the first commands and then just ignore the rest of the code.  I tried a couple different ways of writing it, but all three yielded the result of...not working.

I'll post the two relevant codes below:

Code 1:

```
def findPattern (filename, pattern):
    f=open(filename)

    linecount = 0
    lettercount = 0


    for line in f:
        lineCount +=1
        for letter in range(len(line)):
            if line(letter)==pattern:
                letterCount+=1
                return[lineCount,line]
    return "Did not find " + pattern
```

Code 2:

```
print
filename = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
pattern = raw_input("Enter a pattern: ")

def findPattern (filename,pattern):
    f=open(filename)

    lineCount = 0
    letterCount = 0

    for line in f:
        lineCount +=1
        for letter in range(len(line)):
            if line(letter)==pattern:
                letterCount+=1
                print ("Found pattern " + pattern + " at " + str((lineCount, letter)))
```

I think code 2 would be more likely to work but it isn't yielding any results.  Any input would be appriciated.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable names are misspelled: `linecount` vs. `lineCount`, `lettern` vs. `letter`. Python doesn't always warn against this type of error. If this is just a copying error, then `line(letter)` is the error: an index is given by `[]`. What kind of pattern are you searching for, a single character or a string? `line[letter]` will only return a single character.

Next time, please post not only the code and *that* it gives an error, but also *what kind of* error. Most Python errors result in exceptions being thrown (such as `TypeError`), which can tell you (and us) a lot about what's been going wrong.

Comment: Well the thing was it didn't yield anything, upon typing in the raw_inputs it would just do this:
                         >>> 
So thank you for the prompt response, I actually didn't notice the typos.

Comment: Also, I am searching for a string.  Unfortunately, I was going by code from a discussion class, so I wasn't quite sure what was what.

Comment: Are these the complete scripts? Then the solution is quite simple: you're not calling the `findPattern` function, just defining it.

Comment: Yes, both of them are complete. The only thing that's missing was the findPattern("filename", "pattern").  Thanks again for responding, I'm new at the whole python thing, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I called the findPattern function and finally got a real error:  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 12, in findPattern
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lineCount' referenced before assignment
>>>

Comment: I fixed the spelling error though.

Now we have a new error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 14, in findPattern
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That's the second error I pointed out, function call on a string-typed object. Use `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `line` as a function but it is a string. Use `pattern.find(line)` on each line to find your pattern.